# How to consider custom taxonomy names too on a wordpress search?

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to change wordpress default search behavior in order to consider taxonomies names too. If I inform on the search input the value 'Cybercops', I want the wordpress search to look for posts that have the cybercops word.

But the blog have a custom taxonomy named Heros, and one of the Heros categories could have the name 'Cybercops' too. So, If a post or custom post belongs to these 'Cybercops' Heros category, this posts has to appear on the result of the search.

So far, I have this, because I want to bring future post too:

```
function my_theme_my_custom_search( $query ) {

    if( $query->is_main_query() && $query->is_search() && !is_admin()) {
        $query->set( 'post_status', array('publish, future') );
    }
}

add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'my_theme_my_custom_search' );
```

I tried to use one more **$query->set** using **tax_query** but it doesn't work. Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0):

You can use any of the arguments from the `WP_Query`.

- Source @ https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/

| Parameter | Description |
| --- | --- |
| `tax_query` | [(array) Use taxonomy parameters (available since version 3.1)](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/#taxonomy-parameters) |

```
<?php
$tax = array(
  array(
    'taxonomy' => '_your_custom_taxonomy_',
    'field' => 'slug',
    'terms' => '_your_custom_term_slug_',
  )
);
$query->set( 'tax_query', $tax );
?>
```

Comment: I tried that, doesn't work. I'm manually passing the name that I want, and nothing changes:



`$tax = array(
   array(
    'taxonomy' => 'hero-category',
    'field' => 'slug',
     'terms' => 'cybercops',
   )
);
$query->set( 'tax_query', $tax ); `

Comment: It restrict the search to post tagged `cybercops`

Comment: I know, I'm doing that on purpose. I have one post with this custom taxonomy, and it's not there on the results.